# Can't get cucumber to display nested_attributes when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, nested-attributes

I am testing uploading a document with cucumber and nested attributes. Currently, it is uploading fine when I run in on the rails server, but when I try to test the results with capybaras should method it's failing. Here is my relevant code

Error Message

```
Then I should see the job posted and both files attached         # features/step_definitions/job_steps.rb:40
  expected there to be content "test_doc"
```

Feature

```
Background:
Given I am logged in
And I am on the post a new job page

Scenario: User can post a job with a document and picture attached
  When I post a job with a picture and document attached
  Then I should see the job posted and both files attached
```

Step Definitions

```
When /^I post a job with a picture and document attached$/ do
  fill_in 'Title', with: "Title"
  fill_in 'Description', with: "Description"
  fill_in 'Value', with: '199.99'
  fill_in 'job_job_documents_attributes_0_name', :with => "test_doc" 
  attach_file('job_job_documents_attributes_0_document', File.join(Rails.root, 'features', 'upload_files', 'test.pdf'))
  fill_in 'job_job_documents_attributes_0_name', with: "test_pic" 
  attach_file('job_job_pictures_attributes_0_picture', File.join(Rails.root, 'features', 'upload_files', 'test.jpg'))
  click_button 'Create Job'

Then /^I should see the job posted and both files attached$/ do
  page.should have_content 'Job Created!'   
  page.should have_content 'test_doc'       <------ FAILING LINE
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @job, :html => {name: 'job_form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :description %> <br /><br />
  <%= f.text_area :description %>

  <%= f.label :value %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :value %>

  <%= f.fields_for :job_documents do |document| %>
    <%= document.label :document %>
    <%= document.file_field :document %>

    <%= document.label :name %>
    <%= document.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :job_pictures do |picture| %>
    <%= picture.label :picture %>
    <%= picture.file_field :picture %>
    <%= picture.label :name %>
    <%= picture.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Page Source

```
<p>
    <label for="job_job_documents_attributes_0_document">Document</label>
    <input id="job_job_documents_attributes_0_document" name="job[job_documents_attributes][0][document]" type="file" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="job_job_documents_attributes_0_name">Name</label>
    <input id="job_job_documents_attributes_0_name" name="job[job_documents_attributes][0][name]" size="30" type="text" />
  </p>
</p>
```

So all my non-nested attributes aren't throwing any errors but I can't seem to get capybara to see my nested attributes. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the model actually got created?

Answer (score 0):

In controller at method new you need to build the job_documents, like this

```
@job = Job.new
@job.job_documents.build
```

Also do not forget in your model to add to the attr_accessible the job_documents_attributes